# No food deliveries in my prison

Tags: prison-architect

I have a huge prison with a working canteen and kitchen but I'm getting no food deliveries. Is it a bug or am I being stupid.

Comment: Do you definitely have a delivery area that can be accessed from the road and kitchen and isn't full?

Comment: Could be either, for all we know right now. Can you take a screenshot of the whole thing, so we can see what the problem is? (You can upload it to imgur or something, and post it in the comments here, and someone, probably me, will add it to your question)

Comment: I have a delivery area and all is well but looking at other solution I figured out that it is a reset bug that can be resolved with getting more prisoners, but thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: @Nelson868 When you don't require an answer anymore, then please either self-answer the question by posting an answer yourself or delete it.

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same problem
You need to go into logistics and click on food distribution then there should be a yellow line between the kitchen and the canteen 
If there is no line then click on the kitchen and the  canteen

Comment: Also make sure there are cell blocks assigned to use that canteen (red lines in the logistics screen). If no prisoners are assigned to a canteen the kitchen will not cook food for it even if the kitchen and canteen are linked properly.